How do you gradually blend between transparency based on a geometry?

I've some text geometry that I want to gradually fade out based on some geometry (two boxes in this case).
Any suggestions on how to achieve such a effect?
EDIT:
Here is a blend file based on Jakemoyo answer:


Geometry Nodes tree that looks like this.


Full tree:

Then you just access that value with a shader tree that looks like this.

Result:


Could you append the blend file?
I might be having problems recreating the geometry nodes set-up due to a version difference.

Nevermind it works after finding out I wasn't using multiply vector node, but the regular math node.
I also updated my question to include the blend file. Thanks again.
